# How to position buttons based on the background image

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm working with flutter and I want to create a game, the main screen will have some images around the background. You will be redirected to a screen based on the button you clicked. I have each image and the background.

I don't know how to position the buttons around the background, because it should work for different screens.

Could you help me with that please.

[image]

I expect a guide to solve my problem